# Find if any of the rows partially match a string

Tags: mysql, string, string-searching

I want to see if a table contains any sub-string of a given string.

Let's say I have a string

```
somedomain.com
```

In database I have:

```
blabladomain.com
testdomain.com
domain.com
```

I need to make a query that will return "domain.com" as it is a substring of "somedomain.com".

I don't know if this is even possible in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE `site_core_antispam_banned_domain` (
`domain_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`domain_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `LOCATE()` – as in the other answer – or `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM site_core_antispam_banned_domain
WHERE 'subdomain.com' LIKE CONCAT('%', domain_name, '%') ;
```

The above will look for domains that match *any part* of a given string. If you specifically wanted domains matching the *right side* of the string (for instance, if the domain to match against was `somedomain.com.ro` and you were only interested in `*.com.ro` results), you could make the pattern more specific:

```
SELECT * 
FROM site_core_antispam_banned_domain
WHERE 'subdomain.com' LIKE CONCAT('%', domain_name) ;
```

---

Note: there is no performance guarantee with these queries. The execution plan will likely include either a full index scan - if there is an index on `(domain_name)` - or a full table scan.

Comment: I didn't know is possible with like. Its perfect as its much faster then locate:)

Comment: Why the `CONCAT`? Doesn't `LIKE` '%domain.com%' work just as well (or better)?

Comment: @Verace `'domain.com'` is the value in the column `domain_name`. It will be in the results. `'subdomain.com'` is the parameter/string we are looking for (and all its substrings)

Answer (score 4):

I think all you need is Locate function in MySQL as:

```
SELECT domain_id,domain_name as a 
FROM site_core_antispam_banned_domain 
where Locate(domain_name,'subdomain.com')!=0;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use LIKE. To find a substring located in any part of the string:

```
SELECT domain FROM mytable WHERE domain LIKE '%domain.com%';
```

This will do what you asked. But in your examples "domain.com" is always at the end of the string. To look for strings ending with a certain substring:

```
column LIKE '%substring'
```

Note that `LIKE` is not case sensitive. If you want to do a case sensitive search, replace `LIKE` with `LIKE BINARY`.

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM site_core_antispam_banned_domain
 WHERE RIGHT(domain_name,10)='domain.com';
```

Comment: I dont see how this can work in my case. I need to find all records that are substrings of the given string.

Comment: Add your table structure and your sample output

Comment: You've got it backwards. The OP has a string and wants to find values that *are included* in that string. But you have a string and are trying to find values that *include* that string.