# How performant is finding a substring in database?

Tags: mysql, performance, where, concat, substring

To route requests on my website, I need to query the database to see if the first part of a URL matches a category for an item.

For example:

I have a request to **/animals/dog/darktheme/**. The category is 'animals', thus the `category_url` in the mysql DB is `/animals/`.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT category_url FROM items
    WHERE '/animals/dog/darktheme/' LIKE CONCAT(category_url,'%');
```

[reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203206/find-if-any-of-the-rows-partially-match-a-string/203213#203213?newreg=186682748973403b8bf0ab94c9919b17)

This query will have to run for literally every page load of my site. I'm still in the planning stage, thus can change my design if need be.

Does this kind of query perform reasonably well? Let's say there's 10,000 items and 250 different `category_url`s which are all like `/animals/`, `/birds/`, `/reptiles/`, etc.

Any tips on optimizing performance for this kind of query, or any better ways to do it, from the database/query perspective?

Comment: I use PHP with the `PDO` class/extension and I always use paramaterized queries provided by PDO to prevent sql injection. In case anyone worried.

Comment: How about `WHERE category_url = '/animals' OR category_url = '/animals/dog' OR category_url = '/animals/dog/darktheme'` so an index can be used?

Comment: Might that be faster than the CONCAT option? What about `WHERE category_url IN ('/animals/', '/animals/dog/', '/animals/dog/darktheme/'`? I can see this getting "hairy" if my category_url is something like `/animals/big/furry/`, thus the `OR`/`IN` statement would get very long.  The point about an index being used makes me think, probably faster than the concat option.

Comment: Does `CONCAT` use an index? I'm a PHP developer so I have only... as-needed experience with mysql.

Comment: The problem is not CONCAT but that you apply it to a column. Conditions like `WHERE column = @something` or `WHERE column IN (@some_list)` can use indexes. But `WHERE function(column) = @something` no.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: Your _application_ should extract the 'category', then build a query using that.